# Should I use "on" or "about" instead of "regarding" for this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Is there a major difference and are they all grammatically correct?

> I collaborated with the science department to develop content **on**
> the effects of global warming.
>
> I collaborated with the science department to develop content
> **about** the effects of global warming.
>
> I collaborated with the science department to develop content
> **regarding** the effects of global warming.

Comment: To me (midwest US), "content on" seems less idiomatic than "a paper on", "papers on", or "articles on", but I can't at all explain why. I certainly understand all three sentences to mean about the same thing.

Comment: Yes, they're all grammatically correct; no, there's no major difference. I would probably not choose "regarding" just because the other two are a bit more natural, but all are ok.

Comment: Instructional *content* (or *material*) **on** sounds the best to me. The others are also acceptable.